# Vagrant destroy execute ruby

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I would like to execute a custom ruby code after doing vagrant destroy.

That's the code:

```
class OnDestroyMiddleware

  def initialize(app, env)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env["config"].vm.provisioners.each do |provisioner|
      env.ui.info "Attempting to remove client #{provisioner.config.node_name}"
      `knife client show #{provisioner.config.node_name}`
      if $?.to_i == 0
        env.ui.info "Removing client #{provisioner.config.node_name}"
        `knife client delete #{provisioner.config.node_name} -y`
      end
      env.ui.info "Attempting to remove node #{provisioner.config.node_name}"
      `knife node show #{provisioner.config.node_name}`
      if $?.to_i == 0
        env.ui.info "Removing node #{provisioner.config.node_name}"
        `knife node delete #{provisioner.config.node_name} -y`
      end
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I'm trying this but isn't working:

```
Vagrant::Action[:destroy].use(OnDestroyMiddleware)
```

All of this code is from https://gist.github.com/skippy/1010660

I've got this error on Vagrant::Action[:destroy]

> Message: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for Vagrant::Action:Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers). It allows you to run code after a specific vagrant command.

First you need to install the plugin

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

You'll add the code directly in your Vagrantfile, like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Your existing Vagrant configuration
  ...

  # run some script before the guest is destroyed
  config.trigger.after :destroy do
    info "Attempting to remove client..."
    run "knife client show .."
  end
```

Comment: I've got the following error: *  Unknown configuration section 'trigger'.

Comment: did you install the plugin ?

Comment: I forgot it. The problem now is how to call the function: OnDestroyMiddleware.new.call?? What about the two parameters?

Comment: either you convert your code like it is shown, if you want to use your class, you need to call it `action = OnDestroyMiddleware.new(config.vm)` seems config.vm is only what you need

Comment: `action = OnDestroyMiddleware.new(config.vm).call(config.vm)` : undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)